# Using Python to verify the mouse position is within the circle, when clicking anywhere within the circle.

Tags: python, boolean, mouseevent, pygame

I am working on a project within Python that is to determine the multi-tasking efficiency of a person. Part of the project is to have a user respond to an event on screen using the mouse. I have decided to have the user click within a ball. However I am having issues with my code on verifying that the mouse cursor is actually within the confines of the circle.

The code for the methods in question are below. Radius of the circle is 10.

```
    #boolean method to determine if the cursor is within the position of the circle
    @classmethod
    def is_valid_mouse_click_position(cls, the_ball, mouse_position):
        return (mouse_position) == ((range((the_ball.x - 10),(the_ball.x + 10)), 
                                 range((the_ball.y + 10), (the_ball.y - 10))))

    #method called when a pygame.event.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN is detected.
    def handle_mouse_click(self):
    print (Ball.is_valid_mouse_click_position(self.the_ball,pygame.mouse.get_pos))
```

No matter where I click within the circle, the boolean still returns False.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you would believe that the given code would work...

Comment: I'm not sure how you really find your comment useful to me. I'm not well versed in Python.

Comment: This is at a level much lower than "knowing Python".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know pygame, but perhaps you want something like this:

```
distance = sqrt((mouse_position.x - the_ball.x)**2 + (mouse_position.y - the_ball.y)**2)
```

This is the standard distance formula to get the distance between the mouse position and the center of the ball. Then you'll want to do:

```
return distance <= circle_radius
```

Also, for sqrt to work, you'll need to go `from math import sqrt`

NOTE: you *could* do something like:

```
x_good = mouse_position.x in range(the_ball.x - 10, the_ball.x + 10)
y_good = mouse_position.y in range(the_ball.y - 10, the_ball.y + 10)
return x_good and y_good
```

which is more along the lines of what you have written - but that gives you an allowable area which is *a square*. To get a circle, you need to calculate distance as shown above.

NB: My answer assumes that mouse_position has properties x and y. I don't know if that's actually true because I don't know pygame, as I mentioned.

Comment: With a little messing with some code that worked out perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Also to note, mouse_position took value from pygame.mouse.get_pos which returned a tuple (x,y). After unpacking that tuple, I could go ahead with the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `==` to determine if your `mouse_position` is within that expression computing the allowable positions:

```
>>> (range(10,20), range(10,20))
([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
>>> (15,15) == (range(10,20), range(10,20))
False
```

Comment: That is one of the things I had going wrong in my code. Much appreciated. Not sure why I couldn't see that before.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer. I also don't know pygame, but,

I assume `mouse_position` is the `x,y` co-ordinates of the mouse pointer, where `x` and `y` are integers but you are comparing them against the `list`s returned by `range`. This isn't the same as comparing whether they are *in* the lists.

Comment: Thank you, the comment below showed exactly what you explained and I'm not sure why I could not see that before. Never used range() and assumed it worked in a way that it obviously did not. Thanks for the pointer.